# Texture uniform does not work

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, hlsl, raytracing

So im programming a raytracer at the moment and Im passing a 3d texture from the cpu to the gpu but the gpus texture has not the same values

The uniform part  (its made in Unity):

```
RayTracingShader.SetTexture(0, "_VoxelPosTexture", tex);
```

The shader part:

```
Texture3D<float4> _VoxelPosTexture;

float4 color = _VoxelPosTexture.SampleLevel(sampler_VoxelPosTexture, int3(mapPos), 0);
```

Comment: Can you update this question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example? We'll need to see a big enough code snippet to put into a new, empty project and reproduce the problem you're seeing, without needing to guess at how your variables are defined or when your SetTexture method is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to use texture.load